# How to select a particular line in dynamic content in android

Tags: java, android, styles, spannablestring, spannable

I need to select a particular line within dynamic content from database. In every row of a table, few lines start with <#c>. I want to select and center the line which starts with <#c>. I am using SpannableString. I am able to remove <#c> but all texts become centered.

My problem is I am unable to select the paricular line. In the

```
setSpan (Object what, int start, int end, int flags)
```

How will I write start and end characters?

My problem is with

```
int start and  int end
```

How will I use spannableString.length() for int start and  int end.

Below is like the content.

```
 |<#c>aaaaaaa    |
 |bbbbbbbbbb     |
 |<#c>dddddddd   |
 |cccccccccc     |
 |jjjjjjjjjj     |
 |<#c>ffffffff   |
 |rrrrrrrrr      |
 |ggggggggggg    |
```

I am trying below;

```
    TextView textView1 = ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text2));
    String text1 = args.getString(ARG_OBJECT2);

    SpannableString spannableString;
    Object standard;
    if (text1.contains("<#c>")) {
        spannableString = new SpannableString(text1.replaceAll("<#c>", ""));
        standard = new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
        spannableString.setSpan(standard, 0, spannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textView1.setText(spannableString);

    }
```

I checked with the following:

```
System.out.println("spannableString.length : " + spannableString.length());
```

Result was :

```
I/System.out: spannableString.length : 1763
I/System.out: spannableString.length : 537
I/System.out: spannableString.length : 931
```

spannableString.length() is taking all the characters in the content not taking only the particular lines where <#c> contains.

How to get the length of that particular line which contains <#c>?

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ScrlView"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:width = "0dp"
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

With the above code All the dynamic contents in the row of the table are becoming "centered". I need to center that particular lines which start with <#c>.

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod Old question was regarding multiple style but now question is how to select the line that means how to calculate starting and ending characters with spannableString.length(). Will you give me any suggestion? Actually I am unable to solve the problems that why I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

If your String start with <#c> then if part will execute else String will display as-it-is in else part

```
TextView textView1 = ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text2));
String text1 = args.getString(ARG_OBJECT2);

SpannableString spannableString;
Object standard;
if (text1.startsWith("<#c>")) {
  spannableString = new SpannableString(text1.replaceAll("<#c>", ""));
  standard = new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
  spannableString.setSpan(standard, 0, spannableString.length(), 
  Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  textView1.setText(spannableString);
}else{
   textView1.setText(text1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for support. Problem is same. All the texts become centered. I need to center that particular lines which start with <#c>

Comment: may be you added android:gravity="center" in Textview ,try after removing that

Comment: android:gravity="center" is not in the Textview

Comment: I added xml layout file

Comment: your xml is fine,by using that,line start with <#c> are aligned centered and other line aligned from left.its working for me,may be there will be other issue with your code.